# Beautifulsoup accessing nested HTML tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get prices from an HTML that looks like so:

```
<span id="IKSUD11720" class="prices">
    <span class="listPrice">49,50
    </span>39,50 €
</span>
<span id="IBAU0292101" class="prices">28,95 €</span>
```

Using following code:

`price = x.find('span', class_='prices').text` I get:

```
49,5039,50 €
28,95 €
```

How can I access only the second price of each span? So that the output would be:

```
39,50 €
28,95 €
```

I tried using find_all but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.stripped_strings()` and get last element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<span id="IKSUD11720" class="prices">
    <span class="listPrice">49,50
    </span>39,50 €
</span>
<span id="IBAU0292101" class="prices">28,95 €</span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for span in soup.select('.prices'):
    print(list(span.stripped_strings)[-1])
```

Prints:

```
39,50 €
28,95 €
```

---

Or:

```
for span in soup.select('.prices'):
    print(span.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[-1])
```

---

Or:

```
for span in soup.select('.prices'):
    print(span.contents[-1].strip())
```